# mysql Using lat long columns in linestring mbrcontains

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have latitude and lonitude stored as floats in a mysql table.
I am trying to use a SELECT ... WHERE command to only get row where the line between two set of coordinates in each row are within a boundary i.e

> ...Where MBRContains(GeomFromText('Polygon((50.619 0.479,53.153 0.019,54.089 -3.495,51.504 -2.941,50.619 0.479))'),GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.57846832 -2.12799001, 51.50733566 -0.1276831)')) ....

which works great, however when i change the LINESTRING to

> ... where MBRContains(                             GeomFromText(''Polygon((50.619 0.479,53.153 0.019,54.089 -3.495,51.504 -2.941,50.619 0.479))''), GeomFromText('LINESTRING(`addresses`.`latitude` `addresses`.`longitude`,`addresses1`.`latitude` `addresses1`.`longitude`)'))

It fails. Obviously the select has previously joined to address table to create address and address1 table, which are correct.

any ideas? thanks

Comment: Anyone....?   Please...?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the columns inside the quotes of your LINESTRING, so MySQL is treating that as part of the WKT definition:

`'LINESTRING(addresses.latitude addresses.longitude,addresses1.latitude addresses1.longitude)'`

Since your column values are not dereferenced, this WKT is invalid, and MySQL quietly returns a NULL when an invalid WKT is passed to GeomFromText, causing MBRContains to fail.  Use CONCAT to build up a correct LINESTRING for GeomFromText:

`CONCAT('LINESTRING(',addresses.latitude','  ',addresses.longitude,',',addresses1.latitude....`